# custom directives - child directives do not show up when enclosed within parent directive

Tags: angularjs

Note: ui-grid is name of my custom grid. Sorry about the confusion.

I have a custom directive which will have a child custom directive and will be called in this fashion in the html.

```
<ui-grid resource="/api/data.json">
            <ui-gridcolumns>
            </ui-gridcolumns>
        </ui-grid>
```

When the child directive is enclosed within the parent directive, the console statements do not print, but when the child directive is outside of the parent directive, it prints console.log just fine. Any insight into how to make it work with the child directive within the parent directive is appreciated.

parent directive:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/ui-grid/grid.template.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('linked Grid');
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.onthescreen = 'test value';   
        }]
    };
};
```

Child directive:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/ui-grid/gridcolumns/grid.columns.template.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('linked Grid Columns');
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            console.log('calling Grid Columns');
        }]
    };
};
```

The entire code base is in git for reference.

https://github.com/eshrinivasan/angular-gulp-browserify-boilerplate

Comment: if you want your parent to wrap it's children, you'll have to use `transclusion`, so that the child elements get written into the template of the parent.  otherwise, the parent template *overwrites* the element contents, and the child elements are essentially removed from the DOM all together.

Comment: also, you may want to consider your naming here;  many people may be confused by your question, since there is an angular library [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) in existence already, it may appear as though you are trying to do something with this library and not with your own custom directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve desired behavior use transclusion:

config:

```
restrict: 'E',
templateUrl: 'app/ui-grid/grid.template.html',
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
   console.log('linked Grid');
},
controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
     $scope.onthescreen = 'test value';   
}],
transclude: true
```

and somewhere in template:

```
<div ng-transclude>
   child directives will be placed here
</div>
```